# 'no multipart boundary was found' when testing max upload size using CommonsMultipartResolver

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, file-upload

In real application  i'm using `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` where i define *maxUploadSize* parameter. So I whant to test catching `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` using spring mvc test.

For this i'm adding `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter` in Java:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Autowired
private MultipartFilter multipartFilter;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void init() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac)
        .addFilter(multipartFilter).build();
}
```

In test conext (xml based configuration):

```
<bean id="multipartFilter" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter">
    <property name="multipartResolverBeanName" value="MyMultipartResolverBeanName" />
</bean>
```

MyMultipartResolverBeanName bean is defined in real life context that is added to test context with maven-surefire-plugin.

My test is like in tutorial:

```
@Test(expected = MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
public void testCertSizeInvalid() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(fileUpload(SUBMIT_URL)
        .file(new MockMultipartFile("fileName", new byte[MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE + 10]))
    );
}
```

When runing i getting **Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found** from `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase`

As i understand, in real life browser sets unique boundary in Content-Type header and separates parts in body with this boundary but spring mock test doen't sets boundary wile sending mock multipart request.

So i found `org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter`, create `org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.RequestPostProcessor` where convert body and Content-Type header to correct (with boundary) and add post processor to request builder - **test is passed!**.

**Maybe anybody knows better or more simple way to add boundary to Content-Type header and body of mock request?!**

**PS** 
 
If there is no better way - i can attach my RequestPostProcessor here 
Used versions:

spring-test-3.2.0

commons-fileupload-1.2.2

Comment: Hi, could you sho your RequestPostProcessor here? It will be uper helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: @user2628641 unfortunately i loose this old project(

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice clean way to test MaxUploadSizeExceededException

It involves using Mockito to spy on the MultipartResolver to force the exception to be thrown.

- Using an inner @Configuration class, wire in a multipart resolver that is a Mockito Spy.
- Autowire the resolver into your class
- For the MaxUploadSizeExceededException test cases, stub the resolver to throw the exception and then perform a post with content type MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Here's the code.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMVCConfiguration.class, UploadTest.TestConfiguration.class})
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public final class UploadTest {

    public static final String MERCHANT_AUTH = "MERCHANT_AUTH";
    public static final String USER = "user";

    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
            CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
            resolver.setMaxUploadSize(500 * 1028);
            return Mockito.spy(resolver);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext m_webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private CommonsMultipartResolver m_multipartResolver;

    private MockMvc m_mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        m_mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(m_webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        Mockito.reset(m_multipartResolver);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUpload_FileTooLarge() throws Exception {

        /*
        Force multipart resolver to throw file too large exception
        */
        doThrow(new MaxUploadSizeExceededException(100)).when(m_multipartResolver).resolveMultipart(
            any(HttpServletRequest.class));

        /*
            Do a multipart post. Cannot use fileUpload as that skips calling the MultipartResolver
         */
        m_mockMvc.perform(post("/upload/")
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isRequestEntityTooLarge())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    }
}
```